# Programmatically setting height of LinearLayout inside ScrollView not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` whose unique child is a `LinearLayout`:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/d_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/d_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparency"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
</ScrollView>
```

I later dynamically add children to the `LinearLayout` by using a `LayoutInflator` (let's say 5 children in this example), and they all have a weight of 1 (so equal heights). I want to only have 4.5 children visible at a time. To do this, I have used a `post` method to do change the `layout_height` property of the `LinearLayout` once the height of the `ScrollView` is known:

```
if (n > visibleItems) { // here n = 5 and visibleItems = 4.5
    dScroll.setFillViewport(false);

    dScroll.post(() -> {
        int height = dScroll.getHeight();
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = dLayout.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = (int) Math.round(n * height / visibleItems);
        dLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
    });
}
```

However, when I do this, the `LinearLayout` and its children behave as if their height was set to `wrap_content` (which is not the case). When using the Layout Inspector in Android Studio, I find that the `layout_height` of the `LinearLayout` is set to 1071 (the correct computed value), but the  `getHeight()` method returns 578.

I have tried several combinations of `requestLayout()`, `invalidate()` and `forceLayout()` but it didn't change anything.

Keeping the `fillViewport` property of the `ScrollView` to `true` makes the `LinearLayout` take the height of the `ScrollView`, so in this case 964px instead of the 1071 that I want.

**Edit:** the problem really comes from `LinearLayout`. If I add a `RelativeLayout` between the `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout` like so:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/d_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/d_rel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/d_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/transparency"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and apply the new height to the `RelativeLayout` instead:

```
if (n > visibleItems) { // here n = 5 and visibleItems = 4.5
    dScroll.setFillViewport(false);

    dScroll.post(() -> {
        int height = dScroll.getHeight();
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = dRel.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = (int) Math.round(n * height / visibleItems);
        dRel.setLayoutParams(lp);
    });
}
```

then the `RelativeLayout` takes the correct height (1071px), but the `LinearLayout` within it (that is in `match_parent` height) is still only 578px high.

Comment: How are you evaluating that ScrollView has calculated its height?

Comment: Try setting the `ScrollView` `layout_height` attribute to `wrap_content`..

Comment: @Hed Shafran The `ScrollView` is correctly set to `match_parent` because I want it to take all the available space, when I change it to `wrap_content` it only takes the size of the items that are in it which is wrong.

Comment: @waqaslam I am using the `post` method, I have tried using an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` on its `TreeViewObserver`, the result is the same. The error isn't in the height of the `ScrollView`, when I log it it shows the correct value, and I can see that the `layout_height` of the `LinearLayout` is then correct but not taken into account...